# viewWillTransitionToSize is invoked on all the view controllers

Tags: ios, orientation, device

The viewWillTransitionToSize method is invoked on device orientation. The problem is this is invoked on all the view controllers .
If view controller A initiates view controller B with push segue and then the device is rotated, the viewWillTransitionToSize method from A is also invoked. How to disable this?

Answer (score -1):

You need to put in

> super.viewWillTransitionToSize(size, withTransitionCoordinator: coordinator)
>               handleLevelOrientation()

inside your viewWillTransitionToSize function. Here is my code:

```
override func viewWillTransitionToSize(
               size: CGSize,  
               withTransitionCoordinator 
                   coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
        super.viewWillTransitionToSize(size, withTransitionCoordinator: coordinator)

        handleLevelOrientation()            
    }
```

Just like in viewDidLoad you need to put in a super, so that viewWillTransitionToSize function is not called from all of your view controllers.